# Download binary file from OKHTTP

Tags: android, inputstream, bufferedinputstream, okhttp

I am using OKHTTP client for networking in my android application.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367888/upload-binary-file-with-okhttp-from-resources) example shows how to upload binary file. I would like to know how to get inputstream of binary file downloading with OKHTTP client.

Here is the listing of the example :

```
public class InputStreamRequestBody extends RequestBody {

    private InputStream inputStream;
    private MediaType mediaType;

    public static RequestBody create(final MediaType mediaType, 
            final InputStream inputStream) {
        return new InputStreamRequestBody(inputStream, mediaType);
    }

    private InputStreamRequestBody(InputStream inputStream, MediaType mediaType) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        return mediaType;
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() {
        try {
            return inputStream.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        Source source = null;
        try {
            source = Okio.source(inputStream);
            sink.writeAll(source);
        } finally {
            Util.closeQuietly(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Current code for simple get request is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
request = new Request.Builder().url("URL string here")
                    .addHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();
response = getClient().newCall(request).execute();
```

Now how do I convert the response to `InputStream`. Something similar to response from `Apache HTTP Client` like this for `OkHttp` response:

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

---

#### EDIT

Accepted answer from below.
My modified code:

```
request = new Request.Builder().url(urlString).build();
response = getClient().newCall(request).execute();

InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();

BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(is);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] data = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
input.close();
```

Comment: check my edited answer i'm waiting your feedback

Comment: glad it worked for you man :D

Comment: as a side note, your InputStreamRequestBody is not going to work if there is an ioexception in the request and the HttpEngine is set to retry. See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Call.java line 202, writeTo is called in a while loop. It will cause an error. (I stumbled upon this while uploading from a `content://` inputstream)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Getting ByteStream from OKHTTP**

I've been digging around in the Documentation of *OkHttp* you need to go this way

use this method :

> response.body().byteStream() wich will return an InputStream

*so you can simply use a BufferedReader or any other alternative*

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
request = new Request.Builder().url("URL string here")
                     .addHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
                     .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                     .build();
response = getClient().newCall(request).execute();

InputStream in = response.body().byteStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String result, line = reader.readLine();
result = line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
System.out.println(result);
response.body().close();
```

Comment: The example you mentioned from documentation will work for a request with simple data or webpage but for downloading a binary file, wouldn't I need a bufferedinputstream? So that I can get the bytes in buffer and write them to Fileoutputstream to save in local  storage?

Comment: Edited with solution for binary

Comment: OKHTTP response does not have getEntity() method like Apache HTTP Client. Made edits in the question

Comment: Edited with ultimate answer ;)

Comment: Do not use `BufferedReader` with binary data; it will be corrupted by the unnecessary byte-to-character decoding.

Comment: Why do you **close()** the response body?

Answer (score 218):

For what it's worth, I would recommend `response.body().source()` from [okio](https://github.com/square/okio#sources-and-sinks) (since OkHttp is already supporting it natively) in order to enjoy an easier way to manipulate a large quantity of data that can come when downloading a file.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    File downloadedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
    BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(downloadedFile));
    sink.writeAll(response.body().source());
    sink.close();
}
```

A couple of advantages taken from the documentation in comparison with InputStream:

> This interface is functionally equivalent to InputStream.
> InputStream requires multiple layers when consumed data is heterogeneous: a DataInputStream for primitive values, a BufferedInputStream for buffering, and InputStreamReader for strings. This class uses BufferedSource for all of the above.
> Source avoids the impossible-to-implement available() method. Instead callers specify how many bytes they require.
>
> Source omits the unsafe-to-compose mark and reset state that's tracked by InputStream; callers instead just buffer what they need.
>
> When implementing a source, you need not worry about the single-byte read method that is awkward to implement efficiently and that returns one of 257 possible values.
>
> And source has a stronger skip method: BufferedSource.skip(long) won't return prematurely.

Comment: This approach is also the fastest, since there won't be any unnecessary copies of the response data.

Comment: How handle progress with this approach?

Comment: @zella simply use write(Source source, long byteCount) and a loop. Of course,  you need to get contentLength from the body to ensure that you read the correct number of bytes. Fire up an event at each loop.

Comment: Thanks. But Is there a way without knowing contentLength? Something of `while ((source.read(fileSink, 2048)) != -1)`. In this code i have an issue with casting: Buffer needs, but BufferedSink found.

Comment: Solved! Working code:  `while ((source.read(fileSink.buffer(), 2048)) != -1)`

Comment: Solutions we find ourselves are the one we remember the best. Happy you found a solution.

Comment: @zella can you please provide full code with progress bar...i am trying the same but cant achieve

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it does, but you have to implement a Zip deflater to get all the files you need down the line if you expect to get access to the files inside the archive.

Answer (score 13):

The best option to download (based on source code "okio")

```
private void download(@NonNull String url, @NonNull File destFile) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    ResponseBody body = response.body();
    long contentLength = body.contentLength();
    BufferedSource source = body.source();

    BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(destFile));
    Buffer sinkBuffer = sink.buffer();

    long totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bufferSize = 8 * 1024;
    for (long bytesRead; (bytesRead = source.read(sinkBuffer, bufferSize)) != -1; ) {
        sink.emit();
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        int progress = (int) ((totalBytesRead * 100) / contentLength);
        publishProgress(progress);
    }
    sink.flush();
    sink.close();
    source.close();
}
```

Comment: write downloadFile method

Comment: i cant get body.contentLength()...its always -1

Comment: Not positive but you'll probably want to put the `flush()` and `close()` methods in a `finally` block to ensure that any exceptions will still flush and close them.

Comment: NOTE: `sink.buffer()` is now deprecated in favour of `sink.getBuffer()` (Java) or `sink.buffer` (Kotlin): https://square.github.io/okio/changelog/#version-210

Answer (score 10):

This is how I use **Okhttp** + **Okio** libraries while publishing download progress after every chunk download:

```
public static final int DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE = 2048; //Same as Okio Segment.SIZE

try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(uri.toString()).build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        ResponseBody body = response.body();
        long contentLength = body.contentLength();
        BufferedSource source = body.source();

        File file = new File(getDownloadPathFrom(uri));
        BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));

        long totalRead = 0;
        long read = 0;
        while ((read = source.read(sink.buffer(), DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE)) != -1) {
            totalRead += read;
            int progress = (int) ((totalRead * 100) / contentLength);
            publishProgress(progress);
        }
        sink.writeAll(source);
        sink.flush();
        sink.close();
        publishProgress(FileInfo.FULL);
} catch (IOException e) {
        publishProgress(FileInfo.CODE_DOWNLOAD_ERROR);
        Logger.reportException(e);
}
```

Comment: what  `getDownloadPathFrom` do ?

Comment: write missing methods pls

Comment: i cant get body.contentLength()...its always -1

Comment: `while (read = (source.read(sink.buffer(), DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE)) != -1) {` should be `while ((read = source.read(sink.buffer(), DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE)) != -1) {`

Comment: If you don't call `sink.emit();` in the `while` cycle you'll use a huge amount of memory.

Comment: why no source.close() ?

Comment: Doesn't `sink.flush()` write all the data to the file here. Why do we need to do `sink.writeAll`?

Answer (score 6):

Better solution is to use OkHttpClient as:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
                    .build();



            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

//                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
//                    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
//                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
//                    }
//                    System.out.println(response.body().string());

                    InputStream in = response.body().byteStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String result, line = reader.readLine();
                    result = line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    System.out.println(result);


                }
            });
```

Comment: i cant get body.contentLength()...its always -1

Comment: @HRaval that is not an okhttp issue, that simply means the server didn't send a "Content-Length" header

Comment: @Joolah how to store that file in internal storage ?

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin version based on kiddouk answer

```
 val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
 val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
 val downloadedFile = File(cacheDir, filename)
 val sink: BufferedSink = downloadedFile.sink().buffer()
 sink.writeAll(response.body!!.source())
 sink.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Update in Kotlin to match KiddoUK's answer from 2015 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/413127):

```
val sourceBytes = response.body().source()
val sink: BufferedSink = File(downloadLocationFilePath).sink().buffer()
sink.writeAll(sourceBytes)
sink.close()
```

and to add progress monitoring:

```
val sourceBytes = response.body().source()
val sink: BufferedSink = File(downloadLocationFilePath).sink().buffer()

var totalRead: Long = 0
var lastRead: Long
while (sourceBytes
          .read(sink.buffer, 8L * 1024)
          .also { lastRead = it } != -1L 
) {
    totalRead += lastRead
    sink.emitCompleteSegments()
    // Call your listener/callback here with the totalRead value        
}

sink.writeAll(sourceBytes)
sink.close()
```

Comment: Great answer. It goes without saying that `totalRead` on itself is not an indicator of progress, it needs to be compared with `body.contentLength()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick method to do it.

- `client` - OkHttpClient
- `url` - the URL you wish to download
- `destination` - where do you wish to save it

```
    fun download(url: String, destination: File) = destination.outputStream().use { output ->
        client.newCall(Request.Builder().url(url).build())
            .execute().body!!.byteStream().use { input ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write downloaded bytes into [Shared Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item) on latest Android, you should have `Uri` on your hand instead of `File` instance. Here is how to convert `Uri` to `OutputStream`:

```
fun Uri?.toOutputStream(context: Context)
        : OutputStream? {
    if (this == null) {
        return null
    }

    fun createAssetFileDescriptor() = try {
        context.contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(this, "w")
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        null
    }

    fun createParcelFileDescriptor() = try {
        context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(this, "w")
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        null
    }

    /** scheme://<authority>/<path>/<id> */
    if (scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE)) {
        /** - If AssetFileDescriptor is used, it always writes 0B.
         * - (FileOutputStream | ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream) works both for app-specific + shared storage
         * - If throws "FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" on Android 10+, use android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" on manifest and turnOff/turnOn "write_external_storage" permission on phone settings. Better use Content Uri on Android 10+ */
        return try {
            FileOutputStream(toFile())
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            null
        }

    } else if (scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)) {
        // i think you can't write to asset inside apk
        return null

    } else {
        // content URI (MediaStore)
        if (authority == android.provider.MediaStore.AUTHORITY) {
            return try {
                context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(this, "w")
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                null
            }
        } else {
            // content URI (provider), not tested
            return try {
                val assetFileDescriptor = createAssetFileDescriptor()
                if (assetFileDescriptor != null) {
                    AssetFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(assetFileDescriptor)
                } else {
                    val parcelFileDescriptor = createParcelFileDescriptor()
                    if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                        ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Once you have `OutputStream`, rest is similar to other answers. More about [sink/source](https://square.github.io/okio/#sources-and-sinks) and [emit/flush](https://jakewharton.com/forcing-bytes-downward-in-okio/):

```
// create Request
val request = Request.Builder()
            .method("GET", null)
            .url(url)
            .build()

// API call function
fun apiCall(): Response? {
    return try {
        client.newCall(request).execute()
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
        null
    }
}

// execute API call
var response: Response? = apiCall()
// your retry logic if request failed (response==null)

// if failed, return
if (response == null || !response.isSuccessful) {
    return
}

// response.body
val body: ResponseBody? = response!!.body
if (body == null) {
    response.closeQuietly()
    return
}

// outputStream
val outputStream = destinationUri.toOutputStream(appContext)
if (outputStream == null) {
    response.closeQuietly() // calls body.close
    return
}
val bufferedSink: BufferedSink = outputStream!!.sink().buffer()
val outputBuffer: Buffer = bufferedSink.buffer

// inputStream
val bufferedSource = body!!.source()
val contentLength = body.contentLength()

// write
var totalBytesRead: Long = 0
var toBeFlushedBytesRead: Long = 0
val BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024L // KB
val FLUSH_THRESHOLD = 200 * 1024L // KB
var bytesRead: Long = bufferedSource.read(outputBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE)
var lastProgress: Int = -1
while (bytesRead != -1L) {
    // emit/flush
    totalBytesRead += bytesRead
    toBeFlushedBytesRead += bytesRead
    bufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments()
    if (toBeFlushedBytesRead >= FLUSH_THRESHOLD) {
        toBeFlushedBytesRead = 0L
        bufferedSink.flush()
    }

    // write
    bytesRead = bufferedSource.read(outputBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE)

    // progress
    if (contentLength != -1L) {
        val progress = (totalBytesRead * 100 / contentLength).toInt()
        if (progress != lastProgress) {
            lastProgress = progress
            // update UI (using Flow/Observable/Callback)
        }
    }
}

bufferedSink.flush()

// close resources
outputStream.closeQuietly()
bufferedSink.closeQuietly()
bufferedSource.closeQuietly()
body.closeQuietly()
```

Answer (score 1):

I append my solution here:

```
fun downloadFile(url: String, file: File) : Completable {
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    return Completable.fromPublisher<Boolean> { p ->
        OkHttpClient.Builder().build().newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                p.onError(e)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file))
                sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
                sink.close()
                p.onComplete()
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Rebuild the client is important if you use various middlewares or you encoding the data in json, or find a solution that not encode the response in other format.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val request = Request.Builder().url(URL).build()
    val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()

    val `is`: InputStream = response.body!!.byteStream()

    val PATH = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        .toString() + "/Folder")
    val file = File(PATH)

    if (!file.exists()) file.mkdir()  
  
        val outputFile = File(file, getFileName(URL))

        val input = BufferedInputStream(`is`)
        val output: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

        val data = ByteArray(1024)

        var total: Long = 0

         while (`is`.read(data).also { total = it.toLong() } != -1) {
             output.write(data, 0, total.toInt())
         }

        output.flush()
        output.close()
        input.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).