# why can I only read 2048 bytes at a time from an okhttp.Response InputStream?

Tags: java, android, networking, okhttp, okio

I am downloading a file using an OkHttp GET request:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
...
OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = Request.Builder().url(url).get();
Response response = okClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

I read from the response body and decorating it with a `BufferedInputStream`, with a buffer size of 4096:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream(), 4096);
```

However, when I try to read from the buffer, the first read returns 1179 bytes. After that, I am only able to read 2048 bytes at a time:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true) {
    int bytesRead = in.read(buffer); //bytesRead is always 2048, except the first read
    if (bytesRead == -1) break;
}
```

Several related questions:

1. What could be causing the first read to return 1179 bytes? Some sort of file header?
2. Why are reads from the `InputStream` being paged to a size of 2048 bytes, instead of the value specified by the `BufferedInputStream` wrapper?
3. Is there a way to configure the `OkHttpClient` to read more than 2048 bytes from the buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What could be causing the first read to return 1179 bytes? Some sort of file header?

The HTTP header is 869 bytes for the response you are reading.

> Why are reads from the InputStream being paged to a size of 2048 bytes, instead of the value specified by the BufferedInputStream wrapper?

You'd have to go digging in `BufferedInputStream` to find out why it's not joining two pages together.

The `InputStream` from OkHttp is handing 2048 chunks because it uses a pool of them to save allocations.

> Is there a way to configure the OkHttpClient to read more than 2048 bytes from the buffer?

No.

---

Depending on what you are doing, you'll generally have a much better time using the `BufferedSource` from `response.body().source()` rather than using `BufferedInputStream`. You can learn more about them on the [Okio repo](https://github.com/square/okio#sources-and-sinks).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jake. I wasn't aware of the source() method, I'll check out Okio.

Comment: In this case how can we download a file? 10MB are taking ages to download from my service

Comment: Never mind my question, using this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/3104287) solved speed issue.