# FileSystemResource: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, url, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to create a fil as follows from a URL (my DropBox account), then add it as an attachment to a MimeMessageHelper, but I get a `FileNotFoundException`. What could I be doing wrong?

```
String[] attachments = {"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXX/my%20Letter.docx"};

for (String attachment : attachments) {
    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("url:" + attachment);
    message.addAttachment(file.getFilename(), file);
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: url:https:\dl.dropboxusercontent.com\s\XXXX\my%20Letter.docx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect); message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: url:https:\dl.dropboxusercontent.com\s\XXXX\my%20Letter.docx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

*How can I go about creating a `FileSystemResource` from a Http URL?*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UrlResource` instead of File system resource or download the file using some http client and then attach it to email.

For example:

```
URL website = new URL("http://someurl");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some temporary name");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

And then attach it using `FileSystemResource`

You can use http client for this, for example: [okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893030/download-binary-file-from-okhttp)