# How to download a zip file from dropbox with Okttp

Tags: android, okhttp

How to download a zip file from dropbox with Okhttp in android and extract the file in to `android_assets` directory. i search in SO and find solution for downloading zip file but not find anything for downloading with Okhttp

Comment: What does "`android_assets` directory" mean? With regards to downloading a file using OkHttp, a search on `okhttp android download file` on a major search engine turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893030/download-binary-file-from-okhttp.

Comment: `android_assets` mean a directory where the package is installed. (ex internal storage)

Comment: To write to internal storage, use the `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()` methods on `Context` (and subclasses of `Context`, like `Service` and `Activity`). Then, follow the recipes in the duplicate question, though I recommend [the `okio` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).