# Save big file on Android phone

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory

I try to store some video files on my phone.

When I get the file from the server, I call :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(response.body().bytes());
fos.close();
```

But my file is too big and I get this error message :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 109117339 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
```

What can I do to avoid this error and finally save my file ?

Comment: Well, if the file is bigger than the total amount of memory, then you can't really save it. You could save it to the external card if you have more space there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare ! It works :)