# Connection reset during download - who does the reset? IIS?

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, iis-8

**Problem**

In our webapp (Angular + JAX-RS REST backend running on WebLogic + IIS proxy) we have 1 REST endpoint which returns an XLSX download (octet-stream). These XLSX files can be huge (up to the XLSX limit of 1M rows).

After some time, on slow connections, the download fails (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome devtools).
The exact time when this happens varies:
Some days after 4-6 minutes, other days after 10-12 minutes. No clear pattern.

Fast(er) downloads work fine, are always succesful. I have seen downloads of hundreds of MBs finish succesfully in (eg.) 8 minutes, but others fail at (eg.) 11 minutes.

The problem is that *I do not understand* why the download fails and why the connection is reset. Any pointers or tips on how to test and debug this problem are welcome.
As far as I understand ERR_CONNECTION_RESET just means that *something* reset the connection. Just looking at the response headers gives no indication on who reset it.

**Question**

How can I understand *why* the download *fails* and who resets the connection?
The logfiles do not state which component resets the connection.

**Setup**

The webapp is deployed on WebLogic 12.2 on the internal network.
IIS 8.5 acts as a reverse proxy making the webapp accessible on the internet.

**Details**

- When I download without IIS as reverse proxy (from our internal network), but with a speed limit in Chrome devtools), the download is always succesful. I've had downloads with 50kb/s which finished fine in 2 hours.
  We cannot find any settings in IIS which influence this behaviour, so I am hesitant to definitively conclude that IIS causes the connection reset, since the precise time varies.
- The WebLogic (exception) logs state that writing to the OutputStream fails because of a closed connection. No exceptions or log entries which indicate that WebLogic closed the connection.
- Using other download speeds makes no difference. There is no direct relation to speed and connection reset time.
- The download is never stalled.
- VPN connection does not seem a factor, people with and without VPN experience the same problem.
- Changing proxy is unfortunately not an immediate solution. Large corporate. Without understanding and knowing precisely that (if) IIS is the problem - not going to happen.

**WebLogic exception**

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.convertToSocketException(NIOOutputStream.java:250) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.access$600(NIOOutputStream.java:33) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.flush(NIOOutputStream.java:482) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream$BlockingWriter.write(NIOOutputStream.java:334) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.NIOOutputStream.write(NIOOutputStream.java:220) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.writeToNetwork(JSSEFilterImpl.java:829) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.wrapAndWrite(JSSEFilterImpl.java:789) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.write(JSSEFilterImpl.java:503) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEOutputStream.write(JSSESocket.java:154) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.server.muxers.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:628) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:590) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:474) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$3.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:760) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.write(ChunkOutput.java:373) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:165) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:186) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableOutputStream.write(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:299) ~[org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common.jar:?]
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:317) ~[org.apache.poi-poi-3.17.jar:3.17]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.copyStreamAndInjectWorksheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:501) ~[org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-3.17.jar:3.17]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.injectData(SXSSFWorkbook.java:391) ~[org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-3.17.jar:3.17]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.write(SXSSFWorkbook.java:936) ~[org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-3.17.jar:3.17]
...
```

**IIS logs**
The only line I could find relevant to this problem is:

`1.2.3.4, -, 9/15/2020, 9:20:14, W3SVC3, HSTWEB, 2.3.4.5, 561236, 1813, 9658662, 500, 0, GET, /api/resources/export/FOO, sorting=1,`

Comment: Coul you bypass IIS just to see whether it works or not? Could you paste the exception on Weblogic you have described?

Comment: Yes: Like I said in my details: Bypassing IIS works fine. So I would like to determine with absolute certainty if IIS is resetting the connection.

Comment: What about any log message on IIS?

Comment: You have said there the pattern is not clear because it varies between 8, 11 and more minutes. However, I think it could be more about how long the connection stays inactive, perhaps that is the issue. I am not an expert in IIS so, could you check this parameter connectionTimeout? [IIS parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits)

Comment: You can only use tools like Wireshark to check who resets TCP connections.

Comment: Interesting finding: I updated the IIS connectionTimeout from 2 minutes to 30 minutes. Instead of after ~11 minutes the download now failed after ~40 minutes. Chrome showed that the connection was stalled at around the 12 minutes mark.  

So, changing connectionTimeout did not fix the problem, but may give a clue on what is happening: somehow with IIS as proxy the connection is stalling after 10 minutes.

Any further ideas?

Comment: Please check the error message in the network. you can see which component is faulty in the network.

Comment: @samwu What do you mean with "error message in the network"? Do you mean checking with Wireshark? I will be setting that up later, but do you mean something else?

Comment: I think this could be more about the design of your application; would not it be better to send an asynchronous call to generate a compressed file on a SFTP server and then getting the file when this is ready? While thinking on async I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943766/how-can-i-more-efficently-download-large-files-over-http)

Comment: I have no indications that the current implementation is inefficient or needs rewriting at this point, since everything works perfectly fine without a reverse proxy. Data is streamed to the browser using an OutputStream and StreamingOutput which is for XLSX files efficient and uses relatively low memory. (The XLSX file is not a static file, but generated from content in a database).  

I requested the IIS HTTPERR logs, which I did not know existed. Hopefully they give an indication what is wrong.

Comment: @Bossk I mean in your browser, use F12 to check for error messages in the network.