# Save file into hidden folder in internal storage with download manager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am working on a book application where users would need to first download a book as pdf before reading it. I don't want any user to be able to access any pdf after download except from the application. I am using `Download Manager` which worked well. But am having two challenges. First, the pdf don't get downloaded into the specified folder and the file is accessible. How do effect this?

```
 private void downloadFile() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(document);
                String extension = document.substring(document.lastIndexOf("."));
                mDownloadBtn.setText("DOWNLOADING");
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setTitle(title);
                request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
                request.setDescription("NewFolder");
                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, File.separator + "NewFolder" + File.separator + title + extension);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            } else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddedLibraryActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        //we can use this reference to track the download state of our file.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `DownloadManager` only downloads to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). To download to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), you can download the PDF yourself, using your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., [OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145)).