# Downloading PDF files in internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-internal-storage

I'm making the task of Android.

I download the file from URL and save in internal storage/directory of android phone? my code is written below but this is external storage code I want internal storage code.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(Computer.this,"Please Wait until the file is download",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("url");
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
                    request.setTitle("" + "filename" + ".pdf");
                    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/"+ "filename");
                    refid = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                    Log.e("OUT", "" + refid);
```

That is external storage code but I want to save in internal storage of Android phone.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `DownloadManager` to download directly to [your app's portion of internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You will need to [use OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145) or some other in-process HTTP client API.

Comment: i access the pdf file from internal storage on button click method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getCacheDir(),"filename.txt")));
```

Comment: i use this code but the error is occur 
the null object reference error
i want to file file in internal storage folder

Comment: try

request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "filename.txt")));

Comment: I try this code now but Sir the file saved in sd card i want to save file in phone storage

Answer (score 0):

You can simple just delete this line, `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()`

> By default, downloads are saved to a generated filename in the shared download cache

[From Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri))

Comment: I try this code but the file are saved in sd card downlaod folder. i want to save file in phone storage download folde