# Downalod video and save locally

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want to download files (files will .mp4 and .pdf) and save them locally that only my application can access.

Any solutions?

P.S.-> Saving in data/data can be accessed via Data Explorer from Android studio? Just a question for knowledge.

For reference: As youtube videos gets downloaded and can be viewed in app only.

Comment: You can do easily with firebase

Comment: @Shermano How? I want this to be downloaded from URL and save.

Comment: How what? to download? to store them locally? you'll paste the url on app and the file will be downloaded?

Comment: @Shermano Have you understood the question? What it says? Why should I store on firebase if I can it in device in any other way?

Comment: I did not to be honest, I'm sorry

Comment: How what? to download?-> This says a lot.

Comment: Download to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (`getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`). Exactly *how* to download them depends a lot on where they are. For example, you have a public URL, [use OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare But this needs to be encrypted while storing. Right?

Comment: No. Why would it?

Comment: I am not pretty sure, but Is data/data folder can be accessible in any way like pluging the device in android studio?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you guide on above?

Comment: Until the build is in debug mode.-> Is this the answer you deleted just now?@CommonsWare