# Image URL to File Object

Tags: android, file, imageurl

I'm trying to convert this image url to file object :

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/10211842143528384/picture?height=200&width=200&migration_overrides=%7Boctober_2012%3Atrue%7D
```

this link came from the facebook response after i logged in.

i used this method to convert this image url to File object:

```
  URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(sharePreferences.getPreferencesProfilePicture());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File f = new File(url.getFile());
            Log.d("CHECKER",""+f.exists());
            Log.d("CHECKER",""+f.length());
```

but when i check it's length, its just 0 and the file exist is false.

Comment: You need to [download the content identified by the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

Comment: im confused? why do i need to Download binary file from OKHTTP???

Comment: you don't actually have the file, it's returning the location of where it is, that's why you have to download it

Answer (score 0):

You have a file with length 0 because you are just creating it with the name of the result of url.getFile(), url.getFile() returns a string which corresponds to the fetched file name.So you end up with a file named picture:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/10211842143528384/`**`picture`**`?height=200&width=200&migration_overrides=%7Boctober_2012%3Atrue%7`
 But what about the contents? you have to download them fron the internet as a stream and feed that stream into a file. There many ways of doing that with plain Java. A basic copy-paste from https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file

```java
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(FILE_URL).openStream());
  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME)) {
    byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Since you are using android I would strongly encourage you to use fully featured Network libraries such as OkHttp3, Retrofit or Volley, but guessing your knowledge I think you will do better learning the basics on Java then jump to the mentioned libraries.

Remember, for android you need the INTERNET permission to access the internet, then if you download into a file on the external storage you would also need the EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Snippet for android:

```java
try {
  URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
  conection.connect();

  int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

  // Read from the Network stream
  InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
          .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
          + "/downloaded.png");

  byte data[] = new byte[1024];

  while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
      total += count;
      // Feed the bytes read from the input stream into our output stream
      output.write(data, 0, count);
  }

  // Flushing the out stream.
  output.flush();

  // closing streams
  output.close();
  input.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
```

This snippet does networking stuff so you need to run it on a background thread. I hope my answer helps you, if not, let me know what else can I do for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can i get the File Object then? i'm so confused sorry.

Comment: @netflixspotify the question is if you really need a `File` - why do you think you need it? cannot you just use its `InputStream`?

Comment: Why do you need the file Object? anyways, after the download, you can do `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloaded.png");`

Comment: @pskink i need the File because im going to send it to the server sir