# How to publish a specific file?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app where I embed in assets folder a CSV file about 1MB. This file contains 20.000 records of data and it's for read-only. Until now whenever I need to add/remove some records I publish a new apk with the updated CSV. This happens about once per week and usually, the app has no other changes.

I'm thinking of another way to update the CSV file in the user's device.
One option is the app to download the file from some CDN.
Is it possible through play-store to upload there just the file and somehow to be pushed to the user's devices? I'm not sure if Android App Bundle can be used in my scenario.

Comment: "Is it possible through play-store to upload there just the file and somehow to be pushed to users devices?" -- I don't think so. "I'm not sure if Android App Bundle can be used in my scenario." -- I doubt it. Download the file using OkHttp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just serve the CSV file on the web? easiest solution( i think) is to publish it publicly on github...

Comment: Yes, I can download myself the CSV file. I was hoping with App Bundles there is no need to download 'part' of your app same reason you don't need to auto-update (checking every time when user opens your app if it's latest version), play store does it for you (usually when the app is not running). Also with  >1MB file size there might be scalability problems in the server if the number of users increases.

Answer (score 0):

You can host the csv file on server. If you find its too hassle to build and manage you custom server, you can use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage/). And even better and efficient solution would be to parse the file, insert it into in [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) and when updated, user will only get the update portion