# Syncronously Retrofit request in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying downlaodFile from Api Services so I am using Retrofit library,Below codes working but works runs as a asyncrounously,it starts to download all file at the same time,I want to download files as a sycnronously when one request(download process) is completed and response comes,other request(download process) will work, how can I do this? and how to handle finally all request is completed

```
for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size; i++){                        
      downloadFile(headerData,context,urlList.get(i),fileNameList.get(i),fileType.get(i));
}
```

downloadFile.class

```
public static void downloadFile(String headerData,Context context,String url,String fileName,String fileType){

        RestInterface restInterface = RetroClient.getClientFile(url).create(RestInterface.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = restInterface.doGetFile(headerData);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Downloading FileResult:","" + response.body());
                    boolean success = 
                   Utils.writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body(),context,fileName,fileType);

                    if(success == true){
                        startManager(context);
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TAG", "error" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

RestInterfac class

```
public interface RestInterface {

    @GET(".")
    Call<ResponseBody> doGetFile(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);

}
```

RetroClient class

```
public class RetroClient{

    public static Retrofit getClientFile(String url) {

        String BaseUrl = url + "/";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Sncronously with execute method

```
private static class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        String Url,Header,FileName,FileType;
        Context con;

        public DownloadFileTask(String header,Context context,String url,String FileName,String FileType){
            Url = url;
            Header = header;
            con = context;
            this.FileName = FileName;
            this.FileType = FileType;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


            RestInterface restInterface = RetroClient.getClientFile(Url).create(RestInterface.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = restInterface.doGetFile(Header);
                try{
                    Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                    Log.d("Downloading FileResult:","" + responseBody);
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        boolean success = Utils.writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body(),con,FileName,FileType);

/*                if(success == true){
                    startManager(context);
                }*/
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

calling Download File

```
    public static void downloadFile(String headerData,Context context,String url,String fileName,String fileType){

        new DownloadFileTask(headerData,context,url,fileName,fileType).execute();
}
```

Comment: Use `execute()` instead of `enqueue()`. Note that this whole approach is only sensible for very small files, given that you are loading them into memory. For larger files, please use OkHttp directly and [stream the file to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

Comment: I am edited my code at above using execute method,is it syncronously?