# How do I display the PDF file that I have as a base64 link?

Tags: android, pdf, base64

I want to **display** the **PDF** I got from an **HTTP request**. Now I will tell you in steps how I came to the link I have.

> *First I get a PDF from an HTTP request in the following format as a string:*

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
2 0 obj
<</Length 474/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x����n�0��y��l������Jz��^lZ
...
```

> *Then I encoded it (base64) with this code:*

```
byte[] pdf = pdfCode.getBytes();
String link = Base64.encodeToString(pdf, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

> *And now I have something like this:*

```
VBERi0xLjQKJe+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQoyIDAgb2JqCjw8L0xlbmd0aCA0NzQvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRl
RGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KeO+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vW7vv70wEO+/ve+/vXnvv73vv71s77+977+977+9
77+977+977+9Snrvv73vv71ebFrvv73vv73vv
...
```

**What next, how to get a link from this that I can show?**

Comment: "First I get a PDF from an HTTP request in the following format as a string" -- a PDF is not a string. PDF is a binary format. "how to get a link from this that I can show?" -- show... where? If you want to display a PDF on an Android device, that's not how you do it.

Comment: I showed you above how I got the PDF, whatever it is (that code), it is in string format,
since retrofit2 immediately convert it into a string. I want to display it in webview

Comment: "whatever it is (that code), it is in string format" -- then it may not be a valid PDF. "since retrofit2 immediately convert it into a string" -- then perhaps you misconfigured your Retrofit interface, or you should be using OkHttp and download it to a file. "I want to display it in webview" -- `WebView` has no built-in ability to display a PDF.

Comment: I have this problem for a few months and I skip it every time because whenever I ask a question everyone corrects me but in the end no one gives a specific solution

Comment: For your specific question here, there is no solution. The best solution for most cases of displaying a PDF is to [download it as binary data to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145), then use `FileProvider` and `ACTION_VIEW` to let the user view the PDF in their preferred PDF app.