# How To Download Videos So It Can Be Private To App (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I have a number of videos streamable from different URL links. I want to be able to download these videos using the DownloadManager class so that the downloaded videos can be PRIVATE and ONLY ACCESSIBLE by the app. I understand setting the DownloadManager.request as below

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "fileName");
```

will make the downloaded video accessible by other apps, but THAT IS NOT WHAT I WANT. I want the downloaded videos to only be accessible by my app.
I would really appreciate it if anyone can help with how I can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

store your file on the app's data folder, this path : ContextWrapper.getFilesDir();

Comment: thanks, @Thompson sparta, I forgot to add that I'm not very experienced at this. If you wouldn't mind expanding, HOW would I add this to the DownloadManager?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to download these videos using the DownloadManager class so that the downloaded videos can be PRIVATE and ONLY ACCESSIBLE by the app

That is not possible — if it is "PRIVATE and ONLY ACCESSIBLE by the app", then `DownloadManager` does not have access to it. Your choices are:

- Download using `DownloadManager` to a public location, perhaps later moving the downloaded content to a private location
- Download the content to a private location yourself, such as [using OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145)

Comment: Let's assume I want to download the video using OkHttp, How do I direct it to a private location as spelled in the question above?

Comment: @Eric: [The OkHttp answer that I pointed you to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893030/download-binary-file-from-okhttp/29012988#29012988) is downloading its file to `getCacheDir()`. That is part of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and it is only accessible to your app (except on rooted devices).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's adding up now. One more clarification; I read somewhere that the files(in this case, video) stored in the getCacheDir() gets deleted if the app system deems it necessary, Instead of the getCacheDir(), can I call getFileDir() instead?, if yes, will it the file be stored private to app same as the getCache()?

Comment: @Eric: Yes. Any of the internal storage locations listed in that blog post have the same effect.

Comment: thanks a lot, @CommonsWare. you have been more than helpful. I will try using this knowledge to download some sample Videos.

Comment: I tried the OKHTTP and it keeps giving error. Below is the Error log "I/DOWNLOAD ERROR: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)"

Comment: @Eric: Probably you need to add the `INTERNET` permission to the manifest.

Comment: Yes, I have long provided internet permission in the manifest.xml

Comment: @Eric: Bear in mind that `I/` is an informational message and may not necessarily indicate a problem. Moreover, it feels like something that you perhaps logged yourself, without logging the stack trace of a caught exception. Beyond that, I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] showing what you have tried.