# How to save file to external storage from link using Mediastore

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mediastore

I have an audio class with filePath (which is a link to audio file to AWS S3 file). Here's my function

```
fun download(audio: Audio) {
        val audioOutStream: OutputStream

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${audio.title}.mp3")
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
            values.put(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC}/Soundy/"
            )
            val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            audioOutStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)!!
        } else {
            val audioPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString() + "/Soundy/"
            val audio = File(audioPath, audio.title!!)
            audioOutStream = FileOutputStream(audio)
        }

        audioOutStream.close()
    }
```

It saves audio, but this file contains nothing (It's 0 bytes). How can I save file from Url using Mediastore? My android version is 11.

**EDIT**
Changed my code to:

```
 fun download(audio: Audio) {
       val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${audio.title}.mp3")
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
        values.put(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
            "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC}/Soundy/"
        )
        val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
        val audioOutStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)!!
        val request = Request.Builder().url(audio.filePath).build()
        val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
        val sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(audioOutStream))
        sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
        sink.close()
        audioOutStream.close()
    }
```

Still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you do not do anything with `audioOutStream`, except to close it. If you want to write something, you need to write something. For example, you could [use OkHttp to download the content and write it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145). While that example shows writing to a `File`, Okio also offers a `sink()` extension function on `OutputStream` that you can use.

In other words, going back to your original code, you would have something like this:

```kotlin
fun download(audio: Audio) {
        val audioOutStream: OutputStream

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${audio.title}.mp3")
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
            values.put(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
                "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC}/Soundy/"
            )
            val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
            audioOutStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)!!
        } else {
            val audioPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString() + "/Soundy/"
            val audio = File(audioPath, audio.title!!)
            audioOutStream = FileOutputStream(audio)
        }

        val request = Request.Builder().url(audio.filePath).build()
        val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
        val sink: BufferedSink = audioOutStream.sink().buffer()

        sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
        sink.close()

        audioOutStream.close()
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code example? Just I'm not sure how to integrate it with audioOutStream.

Comment: @DaniilAndreev: In Kotlin, it would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020900/115145), except replacing `downloadedFile.sink().buffer()` with `audioOutStream.sink().buffer()`.

Comment: @DaniilAndreev: Your added code should go after your `if`/`else`. Right now, you only use it in `else`.

Comment: How can integrate it with Mediastore?

Comment: @DaniilAndreev: It is [an extension function supplied by Okio](https://square.github.io/okio/2.x/okio/okio/sink.html) (which you get as a transitive dependency from OkHttp). You will need to add an `import` statement for it. If you are using Android Studio, there is probably a quick-fix to add that import statement.

Comment: I've created an extension fun OutputStream.sink(): Sink, but now I get "Unresolved reference: buffer" and "Function 'sink' without a body must be abstract"

Comment: @DaniilAndreev: That is not what I suggested. Add an `import` statement for the extension function supplied by Okio. That is just `import okio.sink`.

Comment: "okio.sink" sink is not found

Comment: I fixed it by implementation "com.squareup.okio:okio:2.3.0"