# How save the animated WebP Image into Android local storage?

Tags: android, animation, whatsapp, webp

How save the animated WebP Image into Android local storage?. I Wrote code to download webp images to Android local storage it is working fine to download static webp images but the problem comes into the picture when I tried to download the animated webp image. Only the first frame from the image gets saved

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap finaBitmap, String name, String identifier) {
    String root = rootPath + File.separator + identifier;
    File myDir = new File(root);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(myDir, name);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no code that downloads something.

Comment: There is only code that tries to save a bitmap to file.

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` Replace by: `if(!myDir.exists()) if (!myDir.mkdirs()) return;`.

Comment: "only the first frame from the image gets saved" -- there is only one frame in a `Bitmap`. Perhaps instead of decoding the first frame to a `Bitmap`, you could download the file as a file, such as [by using OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

Comment: @CommonsWare you saved my life brother. Thanks. It's working.