# Download pdf from response (okHttp3) - JAVA spring boot / display on browser

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext

I'm working with external API , when I execute one of the request that returns pdf I cannot handle it in the server side .

If I copy paste the api request :
[https://api.worldota.net/api/b2b/v3/hotel/order/document/voucher/download/?data={"partner_order_id"](https://api.worldota.net/api/b2b/v3/hotel/order/document/voucher/download/?data=%7B%22partner_order_id%22) : "0d7836b4-2eba-475f-b2d6-1b95092534b0" , "language":"en"}

the browser open a pdf in the browser and download it .
when I execute this url in the java code how do I return the response as pdf download ? to the client ? which object should I return ?

my code :

```
    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor("api-key", "api-key")).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(
                "https://api.worldota.net/api/b2b/v3/hotel/order/document/voucher/download/?data={\"partner_order_id\":\""
                        + partner_order_id + "\",\"language\":\"" + language + "\"}")
                .method("GET", null).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf").build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        response.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("downloaded completed");
```

thanks for helping .
idan,

Comment: Very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893030/download-binary-file-from-okhttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path path = Paths.get("https://api.worldota.net/api/b2b/v3/hotel/order/document/voucher/download/?data={"partner_order_id":""
+ partner_order_id + "","language":"" + language + ""}");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            // Content-Disposition
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + path.getFileName().toString())
            // Content-Type
            .contentType(mediaType) //
            // Content-Lengh
            .contentLength(data.length) //
            .body(resource);
```