# Android Kotlin - Download video from url to InputStream / RAM without the need of permission and share

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I need to download a video to a file without storing it on the device, only to the memory so I can share it without the need of permission:

```
    lateinit var videoFile: InputStream // or what ever type it is suppose to be!

var videoFileUrl = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"
    
    // download the video to videoFile
    
    val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    sharingIntent.type = "video/mp4"
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoFile)
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share Video"))
```

I've seen other apps doing it so I know a permission isn't required. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

- store files in cache not need permission of storage
- `youtube-dl` it's Backend of any app that allows download from YouTube/fb....

Answer (score 0):

> I need to download a video to a file without storing it on the device

By definition, that is impossible. A file *is* "storing it on the device". This is true for every major operating system.

> so I can share it without the need of permission

You can write whatever files you like to specific places on the device without permissions. These places are identified via methods on `Context`, such as `getFilesDir()` and `getCacheDir()`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific).

You can download to those locations using your favorite HTTP client, [such as OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

You can then share the file from your chosen location [using `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing).

Also, when you *do* share, use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard, as in your example (`video/*`). It is *your* content that *you* are sharing, so it is *your job* to specify what sort of content it is.

Comment: "use a concrete MIME type" ok I edited it, it will always be mp4, a code example how to download the video would be nice though. I can't stand the awful google/android docs it's a mess

Comment: @EduardUnruh: "a code example how to download the video would be nice though" -- I linked to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145) that demonstrates the core portion of this. OkHttp overall has [quite a bit of documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/). "I can't stand the awful google/android docs it's a mess" -- then, perhaps you should read books on Android app development, or take a course on Android app development.

Comment: Well I'm stuck at Builder() I don't know what to import for this crap there are multiple options with okhttp in it. Android is so awful seriously