# OkHttp network interruptions while writing file to disk

Tags: android, okhttp

I am downloading a file via OkHttp3. When I get back the Response `response` as a result of calling `.newCall().execute()`, I am writing the response to the Android device's disk as so:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/4672234
File targetFile = MyFileManager.getMyFile(context);
BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(targetFile));
sink.writeAll(response.body().source());
sink.close();
```

I'm observing strange behavior in some clients where the file will be entirely downloaded, then while they are attempting to write the file to disk, there is a network error. At that time the write to disk is interrupted and I'm left with only part of the file on the file system.

I don't mind the network errors - this is unsurprising as several clients are in very poor network coverage. And with cheap devices. I want to avoid a situation where the network connection is trying to be kept open while the device is writing to disk.

I realize I maybe postulating - is OkHttp leaving the http connection open while I'm writing the file to disk? If so how do I work around this issue - read all of the data into memory immediately, close the OkHttp response, then write that to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the stream to buffer the entire response.

```java
BufferedSource source =  response.body().source();
source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);

File targetFile = MyFileManager.getMyFile(context);
BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(targetFile));
sink.writeAll(source);
sink.close();
```

Comment: Could you explain how this functionally differs from the original code? Does requesting that the BufferedSource buffer the entire response result in the HTTP connection being closed thereafter? I attempted to call response.close() immediately after source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE) but that breaks the write to the sink so I think I'm missing the point.

Comment: By reading the entire HTTP response before writing any of the file, you prevent network problems from occurring while writing the file.