# OutOfMemoryError while using Kotlin's copyTo()

Tags: android, kotlin, file, okhttp

I'm currently facing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception while trying to download large file with OkHttp and then write that file to my custom target file location with Kotlin's copyTo() method. Is there any better option? I don't want to use Android DownloadManager for some reason. Here is my code:

```
  override suspend fun download(
        url: String,
        targetFile: File,
        onProgressChanged: (Int) -> Unit
    ) {

        if (!targetFile.exists()) {
            targetFile.parentFile?.mkdirs()
        }

        okHttpClient.newCall(
            Request.Builder()
                .get()
                .url(url)
                .build()
        ).execute().body?.let {
            startDownload(it.byteStream(), targetFile)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun startDownload(source: InputStream, targetFile: File) =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            source.use { ins ->
                ins.copyTo(targetFile.outputStream())
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Here is my full stack trace:

```
         Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 10373280 free bytes and 10130KB until OOM, target footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 0 bytes). Number of 256KB sized free regions are: 0
    at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:64)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:319)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:306)
    at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-7
Process: ge.mydownloder.mobile.debug, PID: 23901
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 32 byte allocation with 10373328 free bytes and 10130KB until OOM, target footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 0 bytes). Number of 256KB sized free regions are: 0
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.addWaiter(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:651)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1240)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:267)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$Companion.scheduleTimeout(AsyncTimeout.kt:230)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$Companion.access$scheduleTimeout(AsyncTimeout.kt:204)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.enter(AsyncTimeout.kt:57)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:333)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$AbstractSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:339)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:376)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:281)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:189)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.TeeSource.read(TeeSource.kt:24)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$inputStream$1.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:158)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
    at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.copyTo(IOStreams.kt:110)
    at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.copyTo$default(IOStreams.kt:103)
    at ge.mydownloder.data.downloader.CustomDownloader$startDownload$2.invokeSuspend(CustomDownloader.kt:65)
    at ge.mydownloder.data.downloader.CustomDownloader$startDownload$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at ge.mydownloder.data.downloader.CustomDownloader$startDownload$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
    at ge.mydownloder.data.downloader.CustomDownloader.startDownload(CustomDownloader.kt:64)
    at ge.mydownloder.data.downloader.CustomDownloader.access$startDownload(CustomDownloader.kt:24)
    at ge.mydownloder.data.downloader.CustomDownloader$download$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(CustomDownloader.kt:49)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@7ae1d98, Dispatchers.IO]
```

Comment: Please also include the full stack trace as text in your question.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like you are getting an OOME not because you have used too much RAM but because your RAM is heavily fragmented so that there is not even a block with 32 bytes as a block left. Are you performing other tasks in background in your app? On what phone(s) do you see this error?

Comment: @Robert Galaxy S22 Ultra. There is one Service active from which the CustomDownloader's startDownload method is called

Comment: Yeah, this is interesting. It doesn't really seem caused by reading the whole file into the memory. To be honest, it looks like some problem in okio. Do you use the latest version of okhttp/okio?

Comment: @broot Yes of course :( it's really weird as I tried every possible option and still ending up looking for some third-party library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing everything right, there was no problem with inputStream.copyTo(outputStream), it was okhttpinterceptor which was causing the error. I was using ChuckerInterceptor which was downloading and saving a whole file into the memory, So what I did was just **removing that from OkHttp client** and the problem is gone!

Answer (score 0):

you are reading the data in the memory and it gets large!
you should use a buffer to read & write smaller amount of data and avoid reading a large amount of data! because it is being saved to memory and you will get out of memory

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` because you are trying to download a larger file.

So basically, you are trying to download a larger file into your Android Phone's RAM with `OkHttp`. That's the problem.

Comment: It's always better to use the Download Manager comes with the OS itself. As, you are trying not using it, you can use try store it in `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Read this section: [The best option to download (based on source code "okio")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893030/download-binary-file-from-okhttp)

Comment: Already tried it :( I need to use custom okhttpclient and since I cannot do that with DownloadManager, I have to find something else