# Android method InputStream.read() is very slow for multiple tasks

Tags: java, android

I have a task to download multiple files from internet and save them to Android storage.

Files downloading very fast.

```
2023-10-06 13:02:26.412  D  File downloaded: v6:file_1696590146411 | 288 ms
2023-10-06 13:02:26.412  D  File downloaded: v6:file_1696590146412 | 288 ms
2023-10-06 13:02:26.419  D  File downloaded: v6:file_1696590146418 | 295 ms
2023-10-06 13:02:26.572  D  File downloaded: v6:file_1696590146572 | 448 ms
2023-10-06 13:02:26.603  D  File downloaded: v6:file_1696590146602 | 480 ms
```

But after reading buffer and save buffer - time to complete AsyncTask increase

```
2023-10-06 12:59:14.602  D  File downloaded: v5:file_1696589953363 | 1452 ms
2023-10-06 12:59:16.299  D  File downloaded: v5:file_1696589953401 | 3148 ms
2023-10-06 12:59:16.796  D  File downloaded: v5:file_1696589953400 | 3646 ms
2023-10-06 12:59:17.088  D  File downloaded: v5:file_1696589953399 | 3938 ms
2023-10-06 12:59:18.882  D  File downloaded: v5:file_1696589953398 | 5731 ms
```

Looks like reading bytes from InputStream is very slow for multiple files. I can not find anything to make it quicker.

`while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); }`

attaching code project files below

```
package com.kerman.testapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String[] urls = {
                "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/16/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=uAkZwYc5phCRNFTrV_prJ_0rP0EdwJaZ4ctje2bY7aE",
                "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/19/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=7epGozH4QjToGaBf_xb2HbFTXoV5o8n_cYzB7I4lt6g",
                "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/22/4434/3729.jpg?hmac=fjZdkSMZJNFgsoDh8Qo5zdA_nSGUAWvKLyyqmEt2xs0",
                "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008.jpg?hmac=T8DSVNvP-QldCew7WD4jj_S3mWwxZPqdF0CNPksSko4",
                "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/25/5000/3333.jpg?hmac=yCz9LeSs-i72Ru0YvvpsoECnCTxZjzGde805gWrAHkM"
        };

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(this); 
        downloadTask.execute(urls);
    }
}
```

Other file

```
package com.kerman.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadTask";
    private final Context context;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Use ExecutorService to download files concurrently
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(urls.length);

        try {
            for (String url : urls) {
                executor.submit(() -> downloadFile(url));
            }
        } finally {
            // Shut down the executor when done
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void downloadFile(String urlString) {
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadFile(): " + urlString);
        long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Get the app-specific external files directory
                String externalFilesDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();

                // Create a timestamped filename
                String fileName = "file_" + System.currentTimeMillis();

                // Create a FileOutputStream pointing to the external files directory and the filename
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(externalFilesDir + "/" + fileName);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }


                Log.d(TAG, "File downloaded: v6:" + fileName+" | "+Long.toString((System.currentTimeMillis()) - unixTime)+" ms");

                // Close the streams
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error downloading file from " + urlString, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advise

Comment: Your buffer is way too small to be efficient. The minimum buffer size for file operations should be 4K, but as flash uses larger sectors (up to 256KB) my recommendation for buffer size would be 16K or 32K. Or use a BufferedOutputStream with a buffer of 16K.

Comment: "But after saving them - time crazy increases" -- we do not know what the `v5` log lines represent, as that does not appear in your [mcve]. All we know is that you ran the `v5` code before the `v6` code. Beyond that, `AsyncTask` has been deprecated for several years, your 1K buffer is small, and IMHO `HttpURLConnection` is obsolete. If I were doing this, I would [use OkHttp and Okio for handling the downloads to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145).

Comment: `But after saving them - time crazy increases` ! The time of what! Are you downloading them again and now overwriting former files? Tell what you do.

Comment: If AysncTask just download 5 files - every AsyncTask complete in average 300ms. If AsyncTask download 5 files, read buffers and save it to Android storage AsyncTask complete in average 2000ms