# How to replace prepopulated ROOM DB

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have made my ROOM DB, it's prepopulated with necessary data and it is in assets/database folder.

Is it possible to get a newer version of the same DB from URL and replace the existing one, and how? If not, what would be the other best thing and how to do it?

Or maybe download a new version on a second location somewhere, and then empty the original prepopulated one, and copy all data from new to the original!? I don't know what is possible and what would be the best to do

Comment: Files in assets are read only.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get a newer version of the same DB from URL and replace the existing one, and how?

1. Close the `RoomDatabase`
2. Delete the database file, which you can get from [`getDatabasePath()` on `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) (if your database is stored in the normal spot for Room)
3. Download your new database to that same location, such as [by using OkHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012988/115145)
4. Open your `RoomDatabase`